# Is it possible to get a file from a shared folder in a windows 10 computer?

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

I would like to know how I could copy a file from a computer to the local folder, edit them and later copy this file to the computer to update it.

If it is possible, how could I do it?

Thanks.

Comment: You can but you'll need permission on the remote location.

Comment: also do a google search on how to use the following `Environment.SpecialFolder` in regards to copying files to the `Local Folder`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the Standard File Open-Dialog, you get the handle for the StorageFile and then you can do everything.